# What should I use in if statement when the condition is true and I don't want to implement anything?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I don't want to call any function user click on default option. Now my question is should I leave it blank or use **return** or anything else ?

```
if (myPref.getString("font_style_key", "default").equals("default")){

        //return;

    }else {
        if (myPref.getString("font_style_key", "default").equals("font_1")){

            textView.setTypeface(...);

        }else if (myPref.getString("font_style_key", "default").equals("font_2")){

            textView.setTypeface(...);

        }
```

Comment: who said you "have to"  have an empty if? just change it in a negative version of the current condition, and drop the else block

Comment: If you find the positive condition (as in the question) more natural than the negative one (as in Eran’s answer), I see nothing wrong with keeping the code as is. Instead of the commented-out `return`statement I’d put a comment like `// Do nothing here`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make sense to negate the condition, so that the `else` clause is eliminated:

```
if (!myPref.getString("font_style_key", "default").equals("default")) {
    if (myPref.getString("font_style_key", "default").equals("font_1")) {
        textView.setTypeface();
    } else if (myPref.getString("font_style_key", "default").equals("font_2")) {
        textView.setTypeface();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a perfect use case for the [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement. You're going to have several options based on one specific value and it's usually a cleaner code

```
String fontStyle = myPref.getString("font_style_key", "default");

switch(fontStyle) {
    case "font_1":
        textView.setTypeface(...);
        break;
    case "font_2":
        textView.setTypeface(...);
        break;
    // We could add this line if we wanted some default behaviour
    default:
        ...
}
```

Also, beware that invoking `myPref.getString("font_style_key", "default")` several times will always return the same value. You can store it in a variable and save some time

Comment: Sir, I know switch case is the better choice. but sir can you please tell me if user click on default option and there is no **case "default"** available then what will be happend ? will it show any error?

Comment: As stated [in the documentation I linked in the response](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html): `The default section handles all values that are not explicitly handled by one of the case sections`